# Convert anything that's not a number to blank

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of data, a similified version is below:

```
x <- c("1234123xcv?","12341534xxx.","hello","goodbye")
```

What I would like to do is have it return the following:

```
"1234123" "12341534" "" ""
```

I know I can do something like this, where I manually specify each upper/lower case letters and the few special characters that I'm aware of:

```
grep("[A-Za-z\\?\\.]",x,value=TRUE)
```

But I don't know what "else" is in the field that's not necessarily a number. (and can't look through it manually, because it's too large)

With that in mind my question is: Is there a way to specify that you want ONLY numbers to be returned in `gsub()`?

Comment: Numbers or digits? "-1" is a number, as is "3.14", as is "1.2E07".

Comment: In my particular case, it's just digits. I don't (believe) I have any numbers in my data that are formatted like that. The follow much akin to the pattern in the example above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
gsub("\\D","",x) # yada yada yada
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside the brackets, `^` means not.  So, this says replace whatever is not a number with ""

```
> gsub("[^0-9]", "", x)
[1] "1234123"  "12341534" ""         ""
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", x) #......
```

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
[^0-9]*
```

This will match anything that's not a digit, no need to specify which character.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

```
gsub("[^0-9]+", "", x)
```

[^0-9] will replace only one character at once and [^0-9]+ one or more which will be faster.

Comment: False. Look at the output to my answer.  It says replace everything that is not a number with `""`.  The `+` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Gsee, I don't think he was saying your version was wrong. Just that his version will do fewer substitutions by substituting any consecutive non-digits at once. For the same result. He could even have argued that it can be faster this way... Anyway, putting that in a comment would have been better in my opinion.

Comment: @flodel.  Good point.  And w_g doesn't have enough rep to leave comments yet.  I'll edit so that I can un-downvote.

Comment: If speed is an issue, using `perl=TRUE` will also be faster. I find `gsub("\\D+", "", x, perl=TRUE)` to be only marginally slower than `gsub("[^0-9]+", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [\d]. will return only numbers.

Comment: 1. [ ] are not necessary when you have a single element (but what are you to do with it?).  2. \ must be escaped.